# Data Analysis: Image Sharpening through Posterization

Tags: data-analysis

I had this image, a picture of Jupiter:

[image]

I wanted to measure the pixel diameter of Jupiter. As evident, the image is quite blurry, and thus, many value of equally justified pixel diameters can be obtained. To eliminate this I posterised the image (which is technically, quote from Gimp, "designed to intelligently weigh the pixel colors of the selection or active layer and reduce the number of colors while maintaining a semblance of the original image characteristics"):

[image]

With the above result, I obtained three pixel diameters of Jupiter (one from each of the coloured circles), and with a little bit of calculation, realised that the yellow circle gave rise to the most accurate value of Jupiter's diameter (which was surprisingly off by less than one percent!).

**My questions are:**

**1)** Why is my original image like that? Is it due to some form of light scattering?

**2)** Is there a better method of obtaining an accurate pixel diameter than posterising the image

**3)** Is the posterised result expected? Are there names that can be given to the three distinct spherical objects (which seem to resemble shadows, like the umbra, prenunbra, antumbra, etc.)? Is there a reason why the middle posterised object gives the most accurate value?

Comment: You have used an ad-hoc method and you have gotten an ad-hoc result (that happens to match your expectation). For one thing, your image looks totally overexposed, which means that the estimate should be too large. Measure the point-spread function of your telescope with a nearby star. Convolute that point spread function with a variable size model of Jupiter and minimize the error between the convoluted image and the measured one. This will give you a more rational estimate that removes your instrument response somewhat.

Comment: When I perform level-2 posterisation on that same input image I get a similar but *different* output image; the red and yellow bands are thinner than in yours. So it looks like @CuriousOne is right that you got lucky.